# Does texdoc support online automatic downloading of documents?

Tags: texlive, texdoc

If I didn't install the documentation when I installed TeX Live. Is there any way for `texdoc` to automatically download the documents I need? For example, when I run `texdoc XXXX`, `texdoc` automatically gets the corresponding document from CTAN and opens it. The experience is the same as that of users who have installed all the documents of TeX Live.

Comment: no, but you can use the online version [texdoc.org](https://texdoc.org)

Comment: Or search the package on ctan and read the PDF documentation there